# Keycloak fail to intercept and refresh expired token

Tags: http, keycloak

I experience an issue to intercept the Http-request when the token has expired.
When the token is alive, I can intercept the Http-request and I can see it in the console log

**Request intercepted: http://localhost:8500/dummy-endpoint**

**http-interceptor.service.ts:35 Token is a good boy!**

But as soon as the token expires, something intercepts the interceptor(?), and not even the console.log('Request intercepted:', request.url); is printed in the console

I only get this error:

**my-component.component.ts:262  Error while fetching data on initialization: Error: Failed to refresh the token, or the session is expired**

`app-module.ts`

```
import {KeycloakAngularModule, KeycloakService} from 'keycloak-angular';

function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService, env: EnvService): any {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: env.keycloakBaseUrl,
        realm: 'realm',
        clientId: 'app',
      },
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        checkLoginIframe: false,
        flow: 'implicit',
      },
    });
}

// 

  providers: [
    EnvServiceProvider,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService, EnvService],
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpInterceptorService,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
```

`http-interceptor.service.ts`

```
export class HttpInterceptorService extends KeycloakBearerInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private keyCloak: KeycloakService
  ) {
    super(keyCloak);
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('Request intercepted:', request.url);
    if (this.keyCloak.isTokenExpired()) {
      console.log('Token expired, trying to refresh...');

      return from(this.keyCloak.updateToken(30))  // try to refresh 30s before token expiration
        .pipe(
          switchMap(() => super.intercept(request, next)),  // if refresh succeeds
          catchError(() => {  // if refresh fails
            console.log('Token refresh failed, logging out...');
            this.keyCloak.logout(
              window.location.origin + (environment.production ? environment.appUri + '/' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[2] : '') + environment.postLogoutRedirectUri);
            return throwError('Token expired and refresh failed');
          })
        );
    } else {
      console.log('Token is a good boy!');
    }

    return super.intercept(request, next);
  }
}
```

`app-routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',
    component: AnotherComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  },
  {
    path: 'no-permission',
    component: NoPermissionComponent,
    canActivate: [ReverseAuthGuardService],
  },
  {
    path: 'login-success',
    component: LoginSuccessComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'my-component/:selectedStation',
    component: MyComponent,
  },

];
```